# Ria services reference is missing from silverlight 4 on VS2010

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm walking through a tutorial for Ria services and Silverlight 3 however my coding environment is VS2010 (with .Net 4.0 and SL4).  The tutorial references system.web.ria and I can't find that reference at all in the Add References window for VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly has changed to System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server + System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

Check out the [documentation on the breaking changes](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3570).